# deny rule is not filtering entirely

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

The following block

```
    location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
        return 404;
    }
```

is not processing `en/blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml` appropriately.  The intent is to process any request that contains the string `wp-includes`, amongst others.

I expect nginx to return the 404 error, whereas the access is hitting the application server.

Where is the syntax mistaken?

**Update**
contents of nginx -T file

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 130s;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
        ## Block spammers and other unwanted visitors  ##
        include blockips.conf;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

# Security headers
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/10-mod-http-ndk.conf:
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-cache-purge.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-fancyindex.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-headers-more-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-lua.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-passenger.conf:
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_passenger_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-uploadprogress.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_uploadprogress_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-nchan.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_nchan_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/blockips.conf:
deny 185.213.20.172;
deny 104.129.18.6;
deny 185.224.91.73;
deny 176.126.83.15;
deny 69.49.102.227;
deny 60.191.38.77;
deny 209.17.96.66;
deny 80.82.77.139;
deny 184.105.247.194;
deny 184.105.247.195;
deny 104.131.133.207;
deny 80.82.77.33;
deny 151.239.67.109;
deny 77.246.234.70;
deny 213.85.3.11;
deny 45.227.253.36;
deny 185.82.216.97;
deny 185.222.211.54;
deny 82.118.242.240;
deny 97.177.247.162;
deny 118.138.101.236;
deny 213.183.146.74;
deny 5.188.211.15;
deny 85.93.20.58;
deny 203.172.211.4;
deny 77.161.231.173;
deny 35.175.132.238;
deny 45.227.255.149;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf:
### Begin automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby; # If you use rbenv
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
# passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
server {

        server_name testing.sportstours.net sportstours.net www.sportstours.net sportstours.me www.sportstours.me iwanttogoto.com www.iwanttogoto.com muse.iwanttogoto.com reflektor.tv www.reflektor.tv;
#        server_name api.sportstours.net www.sportstours.net www.sportstours.me sportstours.me sportstours.net testing.sportstours.net;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env         production;
        root              /home/deploy/v4/current/public;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/reflektor.tv/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/reflektor.tv/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.reflektor.tv) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


       listen 80;

        server_name testing.sportstours.net sportstours.net www.sportstours.net sportstours.me www.sportstours.me iwanttogoto.com www.iwanttogoto.com muse.iwanttogoto.com reflektor.tv www.reflektor.tv;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gdpr:
server {
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name gdpr.reflektor.tv gdpr.sportstours.net gdpr.sportstours.me gdpr.onereededizioni.eu gdpr.perfectcut.glass gdpr.ellci.net;
# gdpr.sipi.it  has dropped off the face of the earth ?
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env         development;
        root              /home/deploy/gdpr/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gdpr.onereededizioni.eu/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gdpr.onereededizioni.eu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = gdpr.sportstours.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gdpr.sportstours.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gdpr.reflektor.tv) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gdpr.perfectcut.glass) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gdpr.onereededizioni.eu) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = gdpr.ellci.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name gdpr.reflektor.tv gdpr.sportstours.net gdpr.sportstours.me gdpr.onereededizioni.eu gdpr.perfectcut.glass gdpr.ellci.net;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hf:
server {
        server_name hf.iwanttogoto.com;

       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env         development;
       root              /home/deploy/hf/current/public;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ialbum:
server {
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        server_name ialbum.iwanttogoto.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env         development;
        root              /home/deploy/fur/current/public;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
          root html;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ialbum.iwanttogoto.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ialbum.iwanttogoto.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = ialbum.iwanttogoto.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name ialbum.iwanttogoto.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/marchesi:
server {
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name marchesi.reflektor.tv marchesi.iwanttogoto.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env         development;
        root              /home/deploy/marchesi/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/marchesi.iwanttogoto.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/marchesi.iwanttogoto.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = marchesi.iwanttogoto.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = marchesi.reflektor.tv) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name marchesi.reflektor.tv marchesi.iwanttogoto.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mssaccounting:
server {
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name contabilita.sportstours.net;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env         development;
        root              /home/deploy/mssaccounting/current/public;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/contabilita.sportstours.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/contabilita.sportstours.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = contabilita.sportstours.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name contabilita.sportstours.net;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mssimagelib:
server {
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name mss.outreachit.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env         development;
        root              /home/deploy/mssimagelib/current/public;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 404 /404.html;
          location  /404.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location ~ /(wp-content|solr|jsonws|mifs|wp-includes|login.asp)/ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.aspx$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.env$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.production$ {
            return 404;
        }
        location ~ \.git$ {
            return 404;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mss.outreachit.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mss.outreachit.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mss.outreachit.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name mss.outreachit.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/serverip:
server {
      server_name 46.111.191.173 www.46.111.191.173;
      error_page 404 /404.html;
        location  /404.html {
        internal;
      }
      location ~ / {
          return 404;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, but in the config, `passenger_enabled on;` is on the `server` level.

It is possible that this captures the requests.

Try removing the line from `server` level and add:

```
location / {
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Comment: Immediate reaction: this does seem to work. Undergoing further testing.  Passenger's manual explicitely references the server block  https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/bionic/deploy_app.html .  passenger tag added, if maybe they'd like to chime in.

Comment: the documentation does allow the suggested answer: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_enabled   `Context  server, location, if`